# File not found Exception: keystore.jks in build.xml

Tags: java, ant

Now i have the errors

```
"File not found Exception: keystore.jks"
```

when running `ant install-home`.

So, i want to create keystore.jks in aglet/bin and want to put the tag for the file attributes

```
key.store="C:\\aglet\\bin\\keystore.jks" 
key.alias="selfsigned" .
```

But I don't know the tag for this attributes.Please...., I would like to know.

Comment: The question is not clear, what are you trying to do with install-home?

Comment: Now, I am installing the aglet software in Windows. I already installed java, aglet and ant.I also put aglet and ant folder in C drive. After putting them, i set the AGLET_HOME and JAVA_HOME in ant.bat and agletsd.bat. And from command prompt, I run "ant install-home" but it is not successful because there is no file for keystore. And so i put the commanad key.store="..." in build.xml. It is not okay. Please explain step by step configuration for Tahiti server.

Comment: First of all welcome to Stackoverflow. You're expecting that a reader will understand what the "aglet" and "Tahiti" software is. It's important to provide more background when posting questions (instead of answers to comments) and demonstrate that you understand the problem domain otherwise Stackoverflow users will close your question.